# php - mysql: Form handling: auto generating the primary key

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two tables 'X' and 'Y'. The primary key of X is auto-generated by MySQL (auto_increment). The primary key of X is a foreign key in Y. I get values for both the tables using the same form and insert the values into the table using the same PHP file. First I insert the values into table X and get the auto generated ID (primary key) using `$id = mysqli_insert_id($db);` and use $id to insert values into table Y.
My question is **If there are many simultaneous users, is there a possibility to get the wrong id from table X**. Is there a better option to get the correct ID(auto generated) from table X.

Comment: It is a good practice to attach the solutions you've tried along the question, so we can take a look at what you have actually done prior to asking. Right now the question is pretty confusing as the subject of this post and what you are requesting to know are two different things.

Comment: if you wrap both inserts inside the same transaction you shouldn't have any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation for MySql's `last_insert_id()` function, the last insert ID is stored on a per-connection basis, so you're perfectly safe to assume that your ID from table X is the one inserted in your previous INSERT statement.

To quote their documentation at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html:

> For LAST_INSERT_ID(), the most recently generated ID is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. It is not changed by another client. It is not even changed if you update another AUTO_INCREMENT column with a nonmagic value (that is, a value that is not NULL and not 0). Using LAST_INSERT_ID() and AUTO_INCREMENT columns simultaneously from multiple clients is perfectly valid. Each client will receive the last inserted ID for the last statement that client executed.